# Mysql connect host change every time in the docker container,why?

Tags: mysql, docker

In the docker container.I try to login the host mysql server. First the host ip is changed,so confused for me.But second login success. Anyone can explain this strange happening?

I login ip is 192.168.100.164,but the error info shows ip 172.18.0.4,which is the container localhost.

[image]

More info:

```
root@b67c39311dbb:~/project# netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         172.18.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
root@b67c39311dbb:~/project# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.0.4  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255
        ether 02:42:ac:12:00:04  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2099  bytes 2414555 (2.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1752  bytes 132863 (132.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 35  bytes 3216 (3.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 35  bytes 3216 (3.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: why do you need to use the dynamic IPs assigned by docker daemon if you can map the container 3306 port to your 127.0.0.1 and always use 127.0.0.1?

Comment: No, you misunderstand what I said before. 192.168.100.164 is my host machine ip , and in the container which running on host machine, the command: ping 192.168.100.164 work well, but mysql -u develop -h  192.168.100.164 -p raise error: ERROR(1045)...Access denied for user 'develop'@'172.18.0.4' sometimes. The ip 172.18.0.4  in the error is container ip,not I set.

Comment: why not trying `mysql -u develop -h 127.0.0.1` ?

Comment: HEHE... the mysql server which I want logining is on my host machine,not on the container. you know,I am in the docker container now.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `--add-host="localhost:192.168.100.164"` when launching `docker run`. But this is not a good practice to my mind. You should move your mysql database to another container and create a network between them

Comment: How does this solve the problem? According to the screenshot, the connection between the client container and the server is possible, but only on the second attempt

Comment: The connection was working on the first attempt as well. If you see the first attempt error message from mysql, it tells him that the user doesn't have access from the container host, but the connection was ok. Who knows what happened to the access rights to allow connections from `172.18.0.4` or `%` for `develop` user between the attempts? What I recommended was running mysql inside another container, not on the host machine. But even if the author wants to do so I suggested mapping host into the container network with fixed ip

Answer (score 0):

That is true, when we start docker container it is get their own ip for container. You need to map host port with docker container. then, when you try to connect host port it redirect to myssql docker container. Please look at https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

Comment: How does this solve the problem? According to the screenshot, the connection between the client container and the server is possible, but only on the second attempt

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to create a docker bridged network and then create your container using the --add-host as suggested by Alexey.

In a simple script:

```
DOCKER_NET_NAME='the_docker_network_name'
DOCKER_GATEWAY='172.100.0.1'

docker network create \
    --driver bridge \
    --subnet=172.100.0.0/16 \
    --gateway=$DOCKER_GATEWAY \
    $DOCKER_NET_NAME

docker run -d \
    --add-host db.onthehost:$DOCKER_GATEWAY \
    --restart=always \
    --network=$DOCKER_NET_NAME \
    --name=magicContainerName \
    yourImage:latest
```

EDIT: creating a network will also simplify the communication among containers (if you plan to have it in the future) since you'll be able to use the container names instead of their IP.